# IE8 is still caching my requests even with mathrandom

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, caching, openlayers

**TLDR** IE is still caching my requests even with Math.random() included in the URL.

---

So I added math random onto the end of my url:

```
var MYKMLURL = 'http://' + host + 'data/pattern?key='+ Math.random();
```

I also added math random onto my function param:

```
window.setTimeout(RefreshPatternData, 1000, MYKMLLAYER);


           function RefreshPatternData(layer) {
               layer.loaded = false;
               layer.setVisibility(true);
               layer.refresh({ force: true, params: { 'key': Math.random()} });
               setTimeout(RefreshPatternData, 30000, MYKMLLAYER);
           }
```

So the request appears as http://host/data/pattern?key=35678652545 etc.

It changes everytime the request is made.

It works in Firefox & Chrome & Safari etc. But IE8 is still caching the data and not updating my layer.

Any ideas as to why this might be occuring?

---

So i added:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

Still is caching the data. Any further ideas?

Comment: Oh, I've seen this one before. IE is braindead when it comes to caches, and will cache everything in sight, even if the server says otherwise. It takes a couple of magic HTTP headers to convince it otherwise...

Comment: I have the same problems. The meta tags don't work in IE8. I was only able to disable caching on the client-side with an option in the F12 developer tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the answers to this post:

[Prevent IE caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848945/prevent-ie-caching)

Comment: I had a search on SO didnt find that question Thanks for the link:)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with IE and it caching AJAX requests. (Why, God, why would you cache an *AJAX* request?) Worked fine in everything else, but IE required coercing via HTTP headers to not cache the AJAX request.

I've long forgotten the URL, but see:
http://greenash.net.au/thoughts/2006/03/an-ie-ajax-gotcha-page-caching/

Also, the HTTP headers that did it for me were:

```
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
```

...which I quite honestly gleaned off a website somewhere.