# Why captcha image does not change in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, captcha

I'm facing a major problem. When I'm changing the image of my captcha on clicking the link "Not readable? Change text." then in this case only IE8 not changing the image while other browser supports it. If any one knows its reason then plz let me know. My coding is below.
Thanks

```
<div id="captcha1">
    <img src="captcha.php" id="captcha" />
        <br/>
            <a href="#" onclick="
    document.getElementById('captcha').src='captcha.php?'+Math.random();
    document.getElementById('captcha-form').focus();"
    id="change-image">Not readable? Change text.</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, change your Cache-Control header by the following :

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
```

post-check and pre-check are specific to IE from what I've read.

See more doc. on this topic here :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php

And about the way it works :

[image]

> How about an example? Suppose an HTTP server sends an image with the
>   following header: Cache-Control: post-check=3600,pre-check=43200 Both
>   pre-check and post-check specify time intervals in seconds. We tell IE
>   to cache the mentioned image for 12 hours (60 * 60 * 12 seconds). The
>   first hour (60 * 60 seconds) IE will simply display the image from its
>   local cache. However, after 60 minutes we want it to check for a newer
>   one in the background, i.e. it will display the cached one and then do
>   a background check. When 12 hours are up, IE checks for a modified
>   image first.

[SOURCE](http://aspnetresources.com/blog/cache_control_extensions)

Note : clear your cache from the browser before testing ;).

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect an IE8 caching problem; that is your Math.random() not working properly. 
Have a look there : [IE8 is still caching my requests even with mathrandom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002938/ie8-is-still-caching-my-requests-even-with-mathrandom)

Comment: Hii Melvin.. thanks for your suggestion , but there are still some more error. B'cose I'm using the  following code in header for removing caching prob. still its not working. Plz let me know if u know about it

Comment: <?php
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
header('Expires: 0'); // Proxies.
?>